# Operations on data frames in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have two xlsx/csv files of prices for the same products (X1, ..., Xn) at different times (t1, ..., tm) registered by two different institutions. 
For each product and each time point, I'd like to compare the two.

```
    data1 = read.csv("C:/path/to/data1")
    data2 = read.csv("C:/path/to/data2")

    priceXi_vector1 = as.data.frame(data1[c(i_start,i_end), price column])
    priceXi_vector2 = as.data.frame(data2[c(i_start,i_end), price column])
```

Now in order to compare, I'd like to consider the (absolute value of the) difference of the two price vectors. But neither

```
   differenceXi <- priceXi_vextor1 - priceXi_vector2
```

nor

```
   differenceXi[j,] <- priceXi_vextor1[j,] - priceXi_vector2[j,]
```

seems to work (Error: "-" not meaningful value for the latter).

As you may have figured out by now, I am utterly, completely unfamiliar with R. Hence I'd be thankful for any help! (Also if there is a simpler, smoother way of to do what I am trying to do).

Comment: could you provide the `dput(head(priceXi_vector1))` and `dput(head(priceXi_vector2))`

Comment: Also try this `differenceXi <- abs(priceXi_vextor1[,2] - priceXi_vector2[,2])`

Comment: 2. I'll first respond to your second comment, as I'm still figuring out how to respond the first one in a concise manner.

Comment: run `dput(head(priceXi_vector1))` and copy and paste the output of this into your question. `dput` shows you the structure of the `data.frame` `priceXi_vector1`

Comment: I tried what you suggested but my price vectors only have 1 column, so I had to modify it into 
 'differenceXi <- abs(priceXi_vextor1[,1] - priceXi_vector2[,1])' 
I received the same error as above (not meaningful value).

Comment: what is the output of `str(priceXi_vector1)` and `str(priceXi_vector2)`. `str` shows the structure of the R object

Comment: 1.(a) `dput(head(priceXi_vector1))` returns the following: (i=1)

`structure(list(`data1[c(1:122), 7] = c(0.0101482133, 0.0104853258, 
0.0103370286, 0.0126618654, 0.0147776053, 0.0165483989)), .Names = "data1[c(1:122), 7]", row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
`

(b) `dput(head(priceXi_vector2))` returns `priceXi_vector2` as a (huge) list in the console and then: (i=1)

`"Price"), class = "factor")), .Names = "data2[c(5:126), 6]", row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Structure of the vectors: 

`str(priceXi_vector1)` returns `'data.frame': 122 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ data1[c(1:122), 7]: num  0.0101 0.0105 0.0103 0.0127 0.0148 ...`
and `str(priceXi_vector2)` returns `'data.frame': 122 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ data2[c(5:126), 6]: Factor w/ 6828 levels "","0.000100005",..: 176 173 178 243 376 481 550 615 673 725 ...`

Comment: ok i think i see the problem. When you are importing the second csv, some values are missing and it converts everything to factors. You should go back to your original csv and be sure that you dont have missing values and or text within there. It should fix your problem

Comment: also run `?read.csv` to see the options you have when importing csvs

Comment: Alright thanks. Data2 had indeed prices in character format so I changed it to num. However, now I obtain the error " "-" only defined for equally sized data-framed". But both are 122 obs of 1 variable: `'data.frame': 122 obs. of 1 variable: $ priceXi_vector1[c(5:126), 6]: num 0.0103 0.0102 0.0103 0.0127 0.0148 ...` and `'data.frame': 122 obs. of 1 variable: $ priceXi_vector2[c(1:122), 7]: num 0.0101 0.0105 0.0103 0.0127 0.0148 ...`

Comment: Nevermind, found my error. It works now, thanks. I would now manually repeat the above steps for all products (i=1, ..., 118). This means spending quite some time. Do you know a smoother way?